# Сохранить поток Ubuntu 16

Tags: ubuntu, rtsp

У меня есть поток вида

```
rtsp://admin:pass@192.168.0.1:554/mpeg4/ch01/main/av_stream
```

Если я открываю его на ноуте через vlc плеер - видео показывает.
Так же у меня есть сервер Ubuntu 16. Я хочу сделать так, что бы видео сохранялось на сервере.

Пробовал разные решения - ничего не работает. В основном пишет

```
open of `rtsp://192.168.0.1:554/mpeg4/ch01/main/av_stream' failed
```

Как можно сохранить это видео и реально ли это сделать?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16259588/4827341. конечно, логин и пароль, если требуются, надо не забывать указывать в url.

Comment: не работает, я эту статью видел. вот я запустил - http://cloud.w4u.com.ua/index.php/s/87BQLZ5TG8vMH6s. после запуска оно так и весит, когда обрываю, получаю такое - rtsp://admin:123asdf6123as@195.69.244.157:554/mpeg4/ch01/main/av_stream: Interrupted system call
Exiting normally, received signal 2. видео нету

Comment: Ну так vlc умеет работать без гуя и умеет сохранять поток.

Comment: @donRumata, можете подсказать как это сделать?

Comment: https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation%3AStreaming_HowTo/Receive_and_Save_a_Stream

Comment: и это я уже пробовал. ввожу vlc rtsp://admin:pass@192.168.0.1:554/mpeg4/ch01/main/av_stream --sout=file/ps:/tmp/go.mpg - получаю http://cloud.w4u.com.ua/index.php/s/zklQ8rEHlzNeiUg. И так оно висит. Нажимаю Ctrl+C - получаю [cli] lua interface error: Error loading script /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/intf/cli.luac: lua/intf/modules/host.lua:279: Interrupted.  видео нет